# Replace a fragment with same fragment

Tags: android, fragment

i am using different fragments in my app. I want to reuse same fragments for some purpose. For example i have fragemntA with a listview. On list item click i want to add the same fragment again with some other data populated in that list.Again when on item click i want to launch another instance of the same fragment with another data. Like this i have to add many fragments. It is decided by response from server. And i want to add these fragemnts to backstack as well. Is it possible? Then how?

Answer (score 0):

The [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) class is what you are looking for. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20401191/3647221) is a post that shows how to use it.

Comment: U are mistaken..i want to load another instance of same fragment..not another fragemnnt

Comment: When you create another instance of a fragment class, you basically create another fragment. You can replace a Fragment fragment1 by a Fragment fragment2.

Comment: Suppose you want to update listview of fragmentA, right?