# Sliding Up Panel (Umano) facing some problems

Tags: android, android-layout, panel, slidingdrawer, android-screen-support

I successfully created the Sliding up panel in my first screen of app(music player),also i have a navigation drawer. Now the problem is this sliding up panel is only available on the first screen. I want it for all my screens (downloads, etc).I want the same way as in apps like Gaana and Google Play Music.
I refered this while creating sliding up panel

https://www.numetriclabz.com/implementation-of-sliding-up-panel-using-androidslidinguppanel-in-android-tutorial/

please help,Thanks!

Comment: Use `slidingPanel` in `activity` and replace fragments in `activity's` container.

Comment: please elaborate..

Answer (score 0):

**Explaination:-**

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/frag_product_list_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
    app:umanoOverlay="true"
    app:umanoPanelHeight="0dp"
    app:umanoParallaxOffset="0dp"
    app:umanoShadowHeight="@dimen/2dp">

    <!-- Main content, Use this container to transact fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dragView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Sliding content -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dragView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

     <!-- content of sliding panel goes here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

*If you're wondering about `Fragment`, follow this link* - 
[How to do FragmentTransaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401074/how-can-i-implement-fragmentmanager-and-fragmenttransaction-to-replace-just-a-si)
[Official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
**Happy coding!**